# Global workaround for random non-specific include file being included?

Tags: php, iis, include, php4

I'm dealing with an outdated PHP4 IIS server which has odd settings and I absolutely cannot update PHP or modify any server settings.

This legacy site on the server basically has subdirectories which have an `includes` directory so there are multiple `includes` directories, and in my root I do something like

```
include 'includes/nav.php';
```

There are around 10 `nav.php` files in `includes` directories throughout, so sometimes the wrong one gets pulled in.

I found a workaround by just prefixing the absolute local filesystem path to it, eg

```
$base = dirname(__FILE__);
include $base . '/includes/nav.php';
```

However, in order to apply the fix I'd have to alter pretty much every file.

Every file includes the same configuration file though. Is there some ini function trick I could use so that each subdirectory grabs its respective include file from its relative directory path instead of other includes directories?

Comment: are the nav.php files all different, or are they all the same file?  If they're the same file, why not create sym/hard links on the filesystem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding your issue correctly, it looks like changing the `include_path` (either in a php.ini, or by using `ini_set('include_path', '...')` or `set_include_path('...')`) so that the relative include folder is tried first, or before any of the other include folders, might help.